# Sequelize how not to redefine models every time server starts

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

In Sequelize tutorials, it is said that a single model is generated in this way:

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  firstName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  lastName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
});
```

And than saved (i.e. create table) like this :

```
User.sync().then(() => {
  // do whatever
});
```

But I expect to do that just once, I need to create tables just once. So the next time I run the script how to just retrieve models (i.e. tables) that were defined before with the above code.

Comment: Your code already does that.  Sync will only create the tables each and every time if you provide the `{ force: true }` option to the sync call.  In your case it only creates the tables if they don't exist.  Keep in mind though that if you change the schema after the initial sync then Sequelize will not automatically add the changes to your table later!

Comment: Okay, thanks, I got it, but that's kind of illogical IMO.

Comment: Yeah kinda.  https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/v3/lib/dialects/postgres/query-generator.js#L38 . For reference if you're interested.  In Postgres sync ends up using `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in sync method you can pass an option to avoid sync of database tables every time. This option will make sure that your application checks for table in database, if it exist then it will not create otherwise it will create table.

```
User.sync(
{force: false}).then(() => {
  // do whatever
});
```

Let me know if you still face issue. I am using sequalize and i am not getting this issue.

Comment: What I find to be a problem is that I need to redefine the model. IMO, model should be created only once. Then the next time the server starts I want to just get the models that were created on the previous runs.